# How to add registery key-value in Visual Stadio Setup Project to another program?

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have c# program that needed to be in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

To run at startup after installation.

I use Visual Studio 2017 **Setup Project** but in it's Registry tab goes as far as :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\
```

I know a program should not change others registry but in my case, I couldn't find any other way to do it.

I wrote a program to send it's ping or beacon or heart beat and authenticate to a server every N minutes and it should run after reboot.

I tried to wrote a service but as far as i understand i could not send string to service programmatically, it has custom command which it revise only integers. after that i tried to use WCF but it is too complicated for such simple task after that i realize if i could put my program in registry and it run after reboot, it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the key name and select New key, and keep doing that until you need to create an actual name-value pair. That's when you right-click and add New string value.